# Regex Expression to extract 2 integer value from string in C#

Tags: c#, parsing

I have real time response from web service as follows :

```
ok,SIP/2417,15,default,N
```

I can save this in text file.

The only thing change is 2417 and 15.

Now I want to  explode 2417 and 15 from text file and save in variable or database.

For Database I have Column Ext and Ringtime

Comment: Why do you need a regular expression? Split on commas, extract third column, split the second column on slash...

Comment: or... if you want super duper speed, using fixed and unsafe, parse the string for chars in numeric range, and save/add them to an int in powers of 10, use regex, use indexof. Truthfully this question is easily doable by your self in all respects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a generic regex you can try is

```
 Regex r = new Regex(@"([\d]+,[\d]+)");
 string var = "ok,SIP/2417,15,default,N";
 Match match = r.Match(var);
```

if you want list of those vars then below is the dynamic solution for any count of number.

```
 List<int> vals = new List<int>();
 vals.AddRange(match.Groups[0].Value.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)));
```

else if you're going to have fixed two values then.

```
 int val = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[0].Value.Split(',')[0]);
 int val2 = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[0].Value.Split(',')[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for all help, I did ti as below :

Comment: string[] res = response.Split(',');
if (res.Length == 5)  {
                    string Ext =  res[1].Replace("SIP/","");
                    string Ring = res[2];
                    string Hold = res[3];

Comment: great @goga if any of answers help then please mark them as correct

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var test = "ok,SIP/2417,15,default,N";
var regex = new Regex("^ok,SIP/(?<number1>\\d+),(?<number2>\\d+),default,N$");
var match = regex.Match(test);
var val1 = match.Groups["number1"].Value;
var val2 = match.Groups["number2"].Value;
```

But this would also work:

```
var test = "ok,SIP/2417,15,default,N";
var values = test.Split(',');
var val1 = values[1].Substring(4);
var val2 = values[2];
```

Note that they will still be *strings* at this stage, so you'll need to parse them if you require them as integers:

```
var number1 = int.Parse(val1);
var number2 = int.Parse(val2);
```

** `TryParse` is a better option if you go with the `Split` option.

[Try it online](http://rextester.com/GYGQ95345)